# Airplay on new Apple TV (3rd gen.) for second screen not at 1080p

Tags: ios, airplay, apple-tv, uiscreen

I am working on an app that uses Airplay mirroring for a second display that has different content to the iPad itself. I'm using an iPad3 and ATV3 (i.e. released March 2012) attached to an LCD capable of 1920x1080 via HDMI.

With Airplay mirroring, the second screen's *UIScreen* is available through *[UIScreen screens]* array. I was able to get rid of the black borders by setting *overscanCompensation* to 3 but I can only display a 1280x720 image. The monitor is working at 1920x1080 (i.e. checked in its menu, set to "Just Scan", and the rest of Apple TV interface is at 1080p).

When I return the *availableModes* array from *UIScreen* it only has one item "1280x720"!

Does this mean that iOS 5.1 only supports 1280x720 on the new apple tv for airplay mirroring and not 1080p!? or am I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Airplay itself only supports streaming in 720p.  Here is what some clever guys did to get around it but you need to assemble some hardware.

http://appadvice.com/appnn/2011/03/airplay-1080p-format

**EDIT** Oops, apparently you CAN stream 1080p, but you can only MIRROR 720p (not enough memory?? I don't know)

Comment: That's really disappointing. Would have expected 1080p to mean 1080p for everything. I could understand that current wifi might not be able to handle games etc but I'm just trying to display static images which would be fine. Does anyone know if this will be upgraded to 1920x1080 soon. It's apparantly supported using the HDMI adapter and cable.

Comment: The answer to that question will probably be nothing but hearsay.  Actually I made a mistake.  You can stream 1080p but you can only MIRROR 720p.  This might have to do with memory shortcomings....

Comment: I bought a new Apple TV in order to test my mirroring app at 1080p over AirPlay, and then learned that it can still only do 720p for mirroring.  Someone pointed me to the specs for the iPad 3 which make it clear this is the case - 1080p for video content only.  My app is mainly static content, including lots of text, and the differences between using the adapter (at 720p or 1080p) and using AirPlay at 720p are significant - AirPlay at 720p is fuzzy.  FYI, the VGA adapter handles 1080p very nicely too.

Comment: Take a look at how AirPlayKit does the streaming of images. You might find something helpful there. ;) https://github.com/rothacr/AirplayKit