# Underscan issue with AirPlay mirroring

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, airplay

I'm having some issues with AirPlay. The thing is, I'm developing with the ATV3, and my TV set supports 1080p. But when I start screen mirroring and receive the new instance of UIScreen, the bounds and the applicationFrame are both giving me a 720p resolution.

But it gets weird when I actually moved the subviews to a negative value, and the whole screen gets covered. So, technically my iPhone is streaming at 1080p, but the bounds returned by the UIScreen are underscanned.

I've tried modifying the `overscanCompensation` before getting the bounds or the applicationFrame (tried both with all 3 `overscanCompensation` values available) but I'm still getting the same result.

Here is a picture of what I'm getting (sorry, it's the worst picture in the planet, I know, but I was using my phone to stream the image to the ATV :) )

[image: Red view is the 720p reported by the bounds property.]
Red view is the 720p reported by `bounds`.

It gets even weirder when I actually try this out in my ATV2 (it is supposedly limited to 720p even if it supports 1080p) and the result is *exactly the same*.

Anyway, if someone knows the method to get the ***real*** screen display to avoid putting a settings view in my app, I'll really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you positively certain that you are actually seing 1080p on the ATV2 and not some interpolated results?

Comment: Not really but if you give me a while, I'll try to check. Anyway, the ATV2 supports 1080p resolution (you can check that in preferences) but it can't decode video flawlessly with a resolution bigger than 720p.

Comment: AFAIK AirPlay mirroring is limited on the ATV to 720 - but that may be outdated information - just a hint. Ow there is actually a related question here already; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952739/airplay-on-new-apple-tv-3rd-gen-for-second-screen-not-at-1080p

Comment: My TV is so crappy I can't have a 1:1 pixel relation even with an HDMI adapter. Sorry, I think I'll not be able to check this for sure :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting that works best for most TVs is:

```
externalScreen.overscanCompensation = UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetBounds | UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetApplicationFrame; // this is the same as setting it to 3
```

Just setting it to UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetApplicationFrame can cause misalignment of  the UIWindow contents.

3 is a bitmask of UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetBounds(1) and UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetApplicationFrame(2) for those wondering where that number comes from and why it works.

Comment: Swift Version: `externalScreen.overscanCompensation = UIScreenOverscanCompensation(rawValue: 3)!1

Answer (score 2):

When you mentioned that you tried all 3 `overscanCompensation` modes, I presume you mean the 3 *documented* modes:

```
typedef enum {
UIScreenOverscanCompensationScale,
UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetBounds,
UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetApplicationFrame,
} UIScreenOverscanCompensation;
```

However, there is a fourth mode, which is not there, but should fix your problems: just set your `overscanCompensation` to `3`.

Also, take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465712/ios-screen-mirroring-shows-overscan-borders-on-selected-apps).

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Ivan solved the same issue for me! But I also had the borders when using AirPlay Mirroring. I got rid of the borders without setting the overscanCompensation property by changing a setting on my Apple TV: try setting 'Settings > Audio & Video > Adjust For AirPlay Overscan' to Off (default On).