# Size of AppleTv's UIScreen

Tags: ios, apple-tv

Is there a set (point) size for the UIScreen of a tv connected through AppleTV and Airplay mirroring?

Or will the screens of appletv be of different sizes depending on the actual tv device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, the screens of appletv be of different sizes depending on the actual tv device.

If you want get the Sizes of the connected TV's from the Device ,
*Follow these :*

**Notification Center**

```
  NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleScreenDidConnectNotification:) name:UIScreenDidConnectNotification object:nil];
```

**Connected notification**

```
 -(void)handleScreenDidConnectNotification : (NSNotification *)aNotification{
        UIScreen *newScreen = [aNotification object];
        CGRect screenBounds = newScreen.bounds;
        // screenBounds --> Get the size from it
    }
```

Comment: Ok I just realized that the AppleTV3 which supports 1080p normally, only handles 720p when doing AirPlay from apps... as some people are already talking about here http://stackoverflow.com/q/9952739/129202 Would be really nice to have 1080p output.

Comment: Ok the more correct answer should probably be, media streaming using AirPlay probably works in 1080p for media such as video and pictures, while *mirroring* only works in 720p. And it's "mirroring" that will be used for any other case when making apps. The funny thing is that even though it's called mirroring, the content of the two screens are different so the mirroring word doesn't really fit at all. Let's hope Apple clears this up some day...